# can my graphics run 4k resolutions

Tags: gaming, 4k-resolution

I have a Saphire 6990 HD 4G with 4 mini display ports, and 2 cables that run into HDMI's, will 2 connected suffice once put into the same tv? will i need a new GPU?

All the research I've been doing points me to believe so.
Anyone able to shine some light on this?

Comment: Are you interested in running 4k resolution, or gaming on them? Just getting a card to display (and use it in office like tasks) requires way more GPU power than running 3D gaming on it in that resolution.

Comment: For surfing the web/office/email you will be fine.  For any modern 3d video game it will probably be slow and awful.

Answer (score 0):

Your Card can easily display 4k resolution. It will also be able to play most games at 4k with low to moderate settings. Do note that at 4k resolution, even the top performing graphics cards fall short. Consider the Titan for example, which cant play the latest titles with full settings at 4k.

4k Gaming is still in its development stage and better 4k experiences might be delivered later on. For now if you do crave all the settings maxed up at 4k, Crossfire is your best bet.